# Use rest service for authentication and authorization in Spring sequrity

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have `REST` endpoint that provide authentication and authorization service. This endpoint use `Spring Security` and `OAuth2`. In Other side i have an other webApp for UI that consume `REST` service. I want to use `Spring Security` in UI webApp that use `REST` Service for get token and roles. How can I do it? Is there any `AuthenticationProvider` for this or I must implement custom class?

Comment: I would recommend visit the spring official site bookmark tutorial http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your Rest Service an OAuth2 resource server. If you need to transport Roles and other info in your token, I suggest using JSON Web Token (JWT). Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt) which has full source on GitHub